# How to keep PHP opening and closing tags in ckeditor source as html entity?

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, entity

In ckeditor, I'm sharing code snippets such as php, html, etc. So for example I would share this:

```
<?php
//Something here...
?>
```

Which appears in source view as this:

```
&lt;?php
//Something here...
?&gt;
```

When I save it to mysql, the code stays as it should. But when I load up the code, ckeditor changes the code in source view to:

```
<!--?php 
//Something here...
?-->
```

Are there any solutions to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must type your php codes in source view otherwise it's become html code
and for protect it from ckeditor use this code in your config.js file:

```
config.protectedSource.push(/<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added config.protectedSource as Kiyan noted and that works for working within the editor. However to view the page as an article including whatever you added in php I had to add the following in my output article/page:

textarea is the field stored in the mysql database.

```
<?php echo eval('?>' . utf8_encode($row['textarea']) . '<?php '); ?>
```

In the editor if I added some php like <?php include ("whatever.php"); ?>, it nicely includes the whatever.php file.